# How to create value with type defined in other value (stored in DB)

Tags: java

I have a strange job because I have to create value with type defined in parameter from database.
For example: In database I stored two parameters:

> parameterName1 and "double" 
>    parameterName2 and "int"

When I load variable from database I have to create variable in Java- my question how to create variable with type defined in DB cell?
For example:

```
double paramaterName1 = ...
int parameterName2 = ....
```

To stored correctly datas in java from database (if in DB is a double then in java tye should be a double)

There is a method in Java could take a type from parameter??
I heard about java reflection- there is a solution?

Comment: Not sure to understand... So you have a column in db that holds doubles, and you want to know how to read it from db so it will be a double in java? If you use jdbc your result set has proper methods like getDouble(columnName) and getInt(columnName)

Comment: Sure but if I insert to database for example string and I will using in JDBC getDouble() then will be a problem.
I mean that database column define what it is type.
I'm trying make a program which will automate loading a data and typeof this data is defined in database- so changes are only in database, program is not changed - shhould automatically recognize what typpe used (defined in database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the values of a database table in a generic way you can access some meta information via the method [`ResultSet#getMetaData()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData()) giving you an object of class [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html). With it you can determine (among other things) the number of returned columns and the type and name of each column.

And to get the actual column values out of the `ResultSet` you can use the generic method [`ResultSet#getObject(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int)). This gives you (if not null) an instance of a class according to the [JDBC-to-Java-type-mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html#1051555) defined in the JDBC specification, e.g. an Integer for SQL INTEGER, a String for VARCHAR or a java.sql.Date for DATE. The generic `getObject()` method cannot return primitives like `int` or `long`. So the corresponding boxed types like `Integer` and `Long` are returned.

Following a simple but complete example using an Apache Derby in-memory database. Be sure to include the [`derby.jar`](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html) into your project or simply include the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
  <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
  <version>10.11.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

in your Maven POM.

The most interesting part is in `genericQuery()`. The other methods only exists to create a test database with some real values in it.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DbTest {

  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("dbtest");

  // Connection string for an in-memory Derby database
  private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=true";

  // Creates the table PERSON
  private static final String TABLE_DEF = 
      "CREATE TABLE PERSON ( "
      + "ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "
      + "NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,"
      + "BIRTHDATE DATE "
      + ")";

  // SQL query for table PERSON
  private static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM PERSON";

  // INSERT statement to create some test data
  private static final String INSERT_DATA = 
      "INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME, BIRTHDATE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";


  /**
   * Create the table PERSON
   * 
   * @param con
   *          The database connection
   */
  private static void createTable(Connection con) {
    try(Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
      stmt.executeUpdate(TABLE_DEF);
      con.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Database error", e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Insert two records to table PERSON.
   * 
   * @param con
   *          The database connection
   */
  private static void insertTestData(Connection con) {
    try(PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_DATA)) {
      prepStmt.setInt(1, 4711);
      prepStmt.setString(2, "Peter");
      final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      final java.util.Date date = df.parse("1980-03-20");
      prepStmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
      prepStmt.execute();

      prepStmt.clearParameters();
      prepStmt.setInt(1, 4712);
      prepStmt.setString(2, "Mary");
      prepStmt.setDate(3, null);
      prepStmt.execute();

      con.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Database error", e);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Date error", e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Read all columns of all PERSON records in a generic way.
   * 
   * @param con
   *          The database connection
   */
  private static void genericQuery(Connection con) {
    try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY)) 
    {
      // Show some meta data. Most interesting are the column count and the 
      // name and SQL type of each column.
      final ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
      final int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
      System.out.println(String.format("Found %d columns.", columnCount));
      for(int col = 1; col <= columnCount; col++) {
        final String colName = metaData.getColumnName(col);
        final String colTypeName = metaData.getColumnTypeName(col);
        System.out.println(String.format("Column %d: Name=%s, Type=%s", 
            col, colName, colTypeName));
      }

      // Now read all records.
      int recNo = 0;
      while(rs.next()) {
        recNo++;
        System.out.println(String.format("Record #%d", recNo));

        // Read the record's columns. Column indices start at 1. 
        for(int col = 1; col <= columnCount; col++) {
          // The value returned by the getObject() method has a type according
          // to the JDBC to Java type mapping table.
          // So for VARCHAR a String is returned, for INTEGER an Integer
          // and for DATE a java.sql.Date object.
          final Object value = rs.getObject(col);
          if(value == null) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Col #%d: Value is NULL", col));
          } else {
            System.out.println(String.format("Col #%d: Value is %s, Java type is %s", 
                col, value.toString(), value.getClass().getName()));
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Database error", e);
    }
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL)) {
      createTable(con);
      insertTestData(con);
      genericQuery(con);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Database error", e);
    }
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
Found 3 columns.
Column 1: Name=ID, Type=INTEGER
Column 2: Name=NAME, Type=VARCHAR
Column 3: Name=BIRTHDATE, Type=DATE
Record #1
Col #1: Value is 4711, Java type is java.lang.Integer
Col #2: Value is Peter, Java type is java.lang.String
Col #3: Value is 1980-03-20, Java type is java.sql.Date
Record #2
Col #1: Value is 4712, Java type is java.lang.Integer
Col #2: Value is Mary, Java type is java.lang.String
Col #3: Value is NULL
```